# Oracle - Insert Stored Procedure Foreign Key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

**Instructions:**

Create two tables, named ***employees*** and ***departments***. Preface the table names with your initials. Link the two tables (foreign key) by a column called ***dept***. Make up a few column names for each table.

Employees Table:

```
create table bsemployees(
dept        number primary key,
empName     varchar2(20),
salary      number
);
```

Departments Table:

```
create table bsdepartments(
dept        number references bsemployees(dept),
deptName    varchar2(20)
);
```

Write the following stored procedures:

•   Insert a row into the ***employees*** table. If the department does not exist. Insert it into the ***departments*** table.

```
create or replace procedure sp_employees(
    a_dept IN number, 
    a_empName IN varchar2, 
    a_salary IN number
)
as
    vCount  number;
BEGIN   
    sp_check_dept(a_dept,vCount);

    insert into bsemployees values(a_dept, a_empName, a_salary);

    if vCount = 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('**DEPT DOES NOT EXIST**');
        insert into bsdepartments (dept, deptName) values(a_dept, NULL);
    end if;
END;
/

create or replace procedure sp_check_dept(
    a_dept IN number,
    vCount OUT number
)
as
BEGIN
    select count(*)
    into vCount
    from bsdepartments
    where dept = a_dept;
end;
/
```

•  Insert a row into the departments table.

```
create or replace procedure sp_departments(
    a_dept IN number, 
    a_deptName IN varchar2
)
as
BEGIN
    insert into bsdepartments values(a_dept, a_deptName);
END;
/
```

I've got it pretty much all down for this assignment except for the fact that when I try to insert a row into the ***departments*** table I am getting a integrity constraint - parent key not found error.

If I do `execute sp_employees(5, 'John Doe', 90000);` It will display `***DEPT DOES NOT EXIST***` and will go ahead and insert the data into ***bsemployees*** and insert the dept# into ***bsdepartments*** and the deptName will be left blank based on my if-then statement. Doing a select(*) shows me this.

However if I go ahead and do `execute sp_departments(1, 'human resources');` to place a row into ***departments*** I get the parent key error. I understand that I am trying to insert something that has no parent key but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table design isn't quite correct - the dept primary key needs to be added as a foreign key to employee (not as the primary key), and employee should have its own primary key:

```
create table bsdepartments(
  dept        number primary key,
  deptName    varchar2(20)
);


create table bsemployees(
  empName     varchar2(20) primary key,
  dept        number references bsdepartments(dept),
  salary      number
);
```

You can then do the 'add if not exists' logic in the check_dept proc:

```
create or replace procedure sp_check_dept(
    a_dept IN number
)
as
   vCount number
BEGIN
    select count(*)
        into vCount
        from bsdepartments
        where dept = a_dept;

    if (vCount = 0) then
        dbms_output.put_line('**DEPT DOES NOT EXIST**');
        insert into bsdepartments (dept, deptName) values(a_dept, NULL);
    end if;
end;
```

Which then simplifies the employee insertion proc as it should be guaranteed of a department:

```
create or replace procedure sp_insertEmployee(
    a_dept IN number, 
    a_empName IN varchar2, 
    a_salary IN number
)
as
BEGIN   
    sp_check_dept(a_dept);

    insert into bsemployees values(a_dept, a_empName, a_salary);
END
```

Notes

- Recommend that you name the procs in alignment with their purpose, e.g. `insertEmployee` vs just `employees`
- As you've noted, the problem with the 'add if not exists' approach is that you do not have sufficient data to completely populate the `department` table, hence the null column (but this is what your lecturer asked for)

Answer (score 1):

Your realation to table `department` is bad. It should linked as below

```
create table bsdepartments(
dept        number primary key,
deptName    varchar2(20)
);
```

and it should be linked to employee table

```
create table bsemployees(
dept        number references bsdepartments(dept),
empName     varchar2(20),
salary      number
);
```

Then if you try inserting `execute sp_departments(1, 'human resources');` it will execute
an then you have to insert the employee.

Here the employee is related to department not the department is related to employee.